# Closing DB connections after they have been reused

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, connection-pooling

this is the situation:

1. I have a django service running in a serverless environment (AWS lambda)
2. The serverless environment creates a docker image out of my django service
3. Every few minutes it launches the container and executes whatever is in my service
4. A docker image is createad as a snapshot of the service meaning database connections are put in the image as well.
5. When a container is launched and it executes my code - previous connections are reused regardless the fact that they might be gone or reused by other services.
6. I get Database Interface errors.
7. So what i do - every time before executing my code logic, i close all connections (django will recreate new ones as needed)
8. As it solves the problem for the current service - it completely destroys other services which might have reused the connection (through something called database connection pooling)
9. When my django service closes it's connections - there is a possibility, that old previous connection is now reused by other service and my django service just destroys it.

**How do i make sure my django service does not kill a connection but rather returns to the connection pool and simply grabs any other awailable connection?**

Comment: I have an idea. How about i close all connections after my code is executed? This would mean docker will not put any connections to the image since there are none. Plus - as the code will be executed again - it will get/create connections, use them and at the end - return/destroy them.

Comment: I found one more possible solution:

from django.db import connections

for conn in connections.all():

    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()

Comment: Well I can assure that non of these solutions work

Comment: It seems like you're doing something strange with Django's connection handling. If it's run normally it should handle closing its own connections with no problems like this. Alternatively, you may have something else going on that's causing what you're seeing instead of what you seem to think it is.